# Show address fields in form registration in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, address

I have created another form registration for customer and according to group he will be redirected to a form. I added the fields of address in the first one by adding this code in `customer_account_create.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_form_register">
            <action method="setShowAddressFields">
                <argument name="show.address.fields" xsi:type="boolean">true</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

but I don't know how to do it for the second. I also tried to do the same in this XML by duplicating the reference block :

```
<referenceBlock name="customer_form_register_2">
    <action method="setShowAddressFields">
        <argument name="show.address.fields" xsi:type="boolean">true</argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

but I got this error [image: Fatal error]

so how to fix this please

Comment: i even tried in the register2.phtml to put setShowFieldsAddress(true) but same error so how to fix that  ?

Comment: Seems you have implement the customer registration form at the custom page. I guess that you don't implement customer registration form at  this page

Comment: i am sorry but i did not understand your note

Comment: Mean you have to try to implementing customer registration at custom page?

Comment: what is implementi,g what does this mean ?

Comment: how to implement  customer registration at custom page ?